# How to add text documents into a file using Batch

Tags: batch-file

Is it possible to create a text file and place it in an existing file using Batch? What I mean is when I type `echo %input%>document.txt` it obviously saves it as a text document, but what I want to happen is for it to automatically place that text document into an existing file that I have previously created. Do I have to call the folder name? I'm honestly lost on how to do this. Any help would be great!

Comment: You mean you want to append text to a file? or you want to save your file to a folder other than the current directory?

Comment: I am wanting to save my file to a folder other than the current directory

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing

```
echo %input%>document.txt
```

You can specify the entire path of the text document

```
echo %input%>C:\path\to\document.txt
```

Obviously you need to change the path to be whatever you want.

Comment: It didn't work, I got an error message saying "Access is denied"

Comment: Did you change `C:\path\to\document.txt` to the path that you want to save the document to?

Comment: That error message indicates that you do not have access to create a file in the specified directory.

Comment: Im not sure if I know what to change the path to, sorry that I'm kinda nooby at this, I'm new to batch

Comment: What folder do you want to save this text file to? You need to use the path to that folder.

Comment: The folder name that i created is called "User Profile" (I'm creating this fake game launcher that will log off and shutdown the computer, I'm just using this stuff to make it look more realistic, don't worry, it's not a virus) but anyways... i need to type `C:\User Profiles\document.txt`?

Comment: `echo %input%>C:\User Profiles\document.txt`

Comment: Still didn't work, I still get the `Access is denied` message

Comment: It is 'working' - your account simply does not have access to write files to the directory `C:\User Profiles`. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: Kinda :/ what I don't understand is why my account doesn't have access to write files in the directory

Comment: Are you on a school computer or something? They will often have very limited access to any folders on the C drive.

Comment: No, I'm on my personal laptop at home

Comment: I'll just leave it as-is for now until I can get it to work. Thanks for the help though :)

Comment: Sounds like you don't have admin rights on your laptop.

Comment: I do have admin rights because it's my personal laptop that I have setup myself, I'll figure it out, I usually do

Comment: To test that - Try to create a folder called `User Profiles` in your C drive. The error is a result of not having administrator privileges in the specified folder.

Comment: tony bd, where would I type `>>appends data`?

Comment: No, he's saying that `>>` literally appends data, it adds text to the end of a file. As opposed to `>` which writes over a file. @tonybd I don't think that is what he is looking for.